# Upload folder and all its contents recursively to firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, react-dropzone

I'm trying to upload a folders contents to firebase but am hitting some errors.

I'm using [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) like so:

```
        <section>
            <Dropzone handleDrop={this.handleDrop.bind(this)} onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)} multiple={true} onDropRejected={this.handleDropRejected.bind(this)}>
                Drag a file here or click to upload.
            </Dropzone>
        </section>
```

In my 'handleDrop' function;

onDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage();
        var fileRef = storageRef.ref(file.name);
        fileRef.put(file)
            .then(function (snapshot) {
                console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
            })
            .catch((e) => {
            });
    });
}

I get the error 'net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND' until firebase errors out with max retry counts.